# Do Proficiency Bonus apply to enemies/monsters/NPC?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, proficiency

I'm reading the basic books but this doesn't get explained. Let's have an example: a PC is attacking an AC16 orc with a sword (he's proficient in swords). He rolls a 13 + STR bonus (+ 2) + Proficiency bonus (+ 2) = 17, it's a hit.
Now it's the orc's turn, he rolls a 10 (+ 2) STR bonus + ...proficiency bonus??

Comment: Hello Nacho, and welcome to the site! Kindly take the [tour] and enjoy your stay! Are the two +2's in your computation the strength and proficiency bonuses? You might want to [edit] your question to make it a bit clearer. Thanks!

Comment: @erazorv4 Please do not answer in a comment. See [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6534/33707) post for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good dupe, the linked question is effectively about how to read monster stat blocks, but this question seems to be about whether or not NPCs even have a proficiency bonus in the first place. The example given just happens to be an attack roll - it could have easily been a saving throw or ability check.

Comment: Do they have one to begin with, or what do they get to add it to? I could see this question as it's written applying to either.

Comment: Nacho, could you clarify for us whether the linked question answers your point of confusion, and if not, what exactly you're asking about? (Are you asking whether they have a proficiency bonus at all?)

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, NPCs and monsters have proficiency bonuses too

Monsters have proficiency bonuses and get to use them when appropriate, just like player characters do. While a PC's proficiency bonus is based on their level, a monster's proficiency bonus is based on their CR, according to [this table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#ProficiencyBonusbyChallengeRating) - from a simple +2 at CR 0 to a maximum of +9 for CR 30 creatures.

The stats blocks for published monsters will already be applying the monster's proficiency bonus where appropriate. For example, the CR1/2 [Orc](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/orc) has a greataxe attack:

> **Greataxe.** Melee Weapon Attack: +5 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 9 (1d12 + 3) slashing damage.

That +5 attack bonus includes the Orc's +3 Strength modifier and their +2 proficiency bonus as a CR 1/2 creature.